# How to get the base path in JS

Tags: 7, javascript

I need the base path in my `custom.js` file. I have added this `custom.js` file in my `MYTHEME.info` file.

In `custom.js` file I'm trying to print

```
var baseUrl = Drupal.settings.basePath;
console.log(baseUrl);
```

Gives me empty value.

Comment: Can you try a simple output of Drupal.settings.basePath; on your browser's console? Just to check this first. And what Drupal version are you using?

Comment: Same problem. I am using Drupal 7.41

Comment: This sounds odd, out of the box, Drupal core javascript instantiates this variable, I can see the Drupal.settings.basePath in Firebug on a fresh Drupal install. Do you get any javascript errors on your console? Can you access Drupal.settings or even Drupal on your console?

Answer (score 1):

This variable Drupal.settings.basePath is provided by drupal.js, just make sure the page includes this js file.(right click view source code to check)

If this did not work, you can create your own variable and use it on the client side:

- You can add your custom.js file into your file .info
  `scripts[] = custom.js` or `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','my_module'). '/custom.js');`
- Use preprocess function in a custom module

```
    function moduleName_preprocess(&$vars){
             global $base_url;
             global $user;
          drupal_add_js(array('moduleName' =>
      array(
        'basepath'=> $base_url,
        'another_variable' => $user->uid
           ),'setting');
        }
```

- access the variable into your js file :

```
  var basepath = settings.moduleName.basepath;
```

- that should be it!

Comment: Here's another gem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17992578

Comment: @leymannx However this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Sure, it won't return the right path *when* your Drupal site is located in a subdirectory of the root URL. But on the other hand it's a no-brainer. Quick and easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal.settings.basePath use value from base_path(). Check in php what value returns base_path(). If needed set it up in settings.php

Comment: i have set the $base_url still same o/p getting.

Comment: provide more details, how do you set it and where?